# Gmail API - Push Notifications - Recieving 2 Notifications when new E-mail arrives

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to write a Python script which notifies me everytime when a new message arrives in my Inbox. For this i used the Pub/Sub Service from Google. I already have created the Topic&Subscription as mentioned in the Documentation. I also am using the Pull Mode as defined here:

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull

The Script works but the problem i have is that i always receive 2 Notifications when a new E-Mail arrives at my Inbox ( see photo ):

[image: The red box shows the 2 Notifications which i got when the new Email "Test-Testime" arrived]

The Code until now:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

# TODO(developer)
project_id = "projectgmailapi-366508"
subscription_id = "mysub"
#Number of seconds the subscriber should listen for messages
timeout = 180.0

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
request = {
  'labelIds': ['UNREAD'],
  'labelFilterAction': 'include',
  'topicName': 'projects/projectgmailapi-366508/topics/mytopic'
}
service.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute()

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
# The `subscription_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
# in the form `projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{subscription_id}`
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)

def callback(message: pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message) -> None:
    print(f"Received {message}.")
    message.ack()

streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")

# Wrap subscriber in a 'with' block to automatically call close() when done.
with subscriber:
    try:
        # When `timeout` is not set, result() will block indefinitely,
        # unless an exception is encountered first.
        streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
    except TimeoutError:
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()  # Trigger the shutdown.
        streaming_pull_future.result()  # Block until the shutdown is complete.
```

1. So how can i get only one notification when a new message arrives?
2. Can i filter somehow the events, so only to get notifications excactly once when a new message arrives and not for other events like Deleting, Sending, Reading a message. I only need to get a notification when a new E-mail has arrived.

p.s I also tried to modify the request

```
request = {  
  'labelIds': 
  ['SPAM','TRASH','STARRED','IMPORTANT','SENT','DRAFT','UNREAD'],
  'labelFilterAction': 'exclude',
  'topicName': 'projects/projectgmailapi-366508/topics/mytopic'
}
```

So it excludes all the Labels except of Inbox, but now i'am not receiving a notification at all

Comment: are you sure you didnt add the watch twice?

Comment: yes, i'am sure. I dont know why this is happening. I cant seem to find a solution. I tried to enable "exactly once delivery" but it did not work either, i still get 2 Notifications everytime a new email arrives.

Comment: Cloud Pub/Sub offers at-least-once delivery semantics. Therefore, you are guaranteed to receive one notification but may receive multiple ones.

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72074775/why-does-gcp-pub-sub-publish-a-message-twice

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Pub/Sub offers at-least-once delivery semantics. Therefore, you are guaranteed to receive one notification but may receive multiple ones.

This is a duplicate of [Why does GCP Pub/Sub publish a message twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72074775/why-does-gcp-pub-sub-publish-a-message-twice)

Moreover, for the second part of your question, I think you should remove the UNREAD label from the exclude list.